# Como se puede enviar un formulario en ionic a un correo electronico mio

Tags: ionic, typescript, email, angular

La cosa es que ya tengo un formulario en el que introduce todo lo necesario y que luego recojo estos datos y los muestro con console.log()

La duda está en como puedo hacer para que cuando se le de a enviar en vez de mostrarmelos por la consola, que directamente me envie un correo electronico a una direccion de email mia.

Pongo aqui mi codigo del formulario por si hace falta.

Este seria el html de mi formulario en ionic "sugerir-categoria.html":

```
            <ion-header>

              <ion-navbar>
                <ion-title text-center>
                  <ion-icon ios="ios-bulb" md="md-bulb"> SUGERIR CATEGORIA</ion-icon>
                </ion-title>
              </ion-navbar>

            </ion-header>


            <ion-content padding>

              <form [formGroup]="formularioSugerirCategoria" (ngSubmit)="guardarConsultaDeSugerirCategoria()">
                <ion-list>

                  <p text-justify>Introduce el nombre de una categoria que te gustaria que incluyeramos en nuestra aplicación</p>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-textarea cols="45" rows="6" formControlName="comentario1" placeholder="Introduce la categoria que te interesaría que apareciera"></ion-textarea>
                  </ion-item>

                  <p text-justify>Descripción de cómo te gustaría que esa categoria se implementase en nuestra aplicación</p>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-textarea cols="45" rows="6" formControlName="comentario2" placeholder="Describe que secciones te gustaría que aparecieran"></ion-textarea>
                  </ion-item>

                </ion-list>
                <div padding>
                  <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!formularioSugerirCategoria.valid">Guardar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </ion-content>
```

y este sería el ts de este html: "sugerir-categoria.ts":

```
            import { Component } from '@angular/core';
            import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
            import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

            @IonicPage()
            @Component({
              selector: 'page-sugerir-categoria',
              templateUrl: 'sugerir-categoria.html',
            })
            export class SugerirCategoriaPage {

              formularioSugerirCategoria: FormGroup;

              constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
                this.formularioSugerirCategoria = this.crearFormularioDeSugerirCategoria();
              }

              ionViewDidLoad() {
                console.log('ionViewDidLoad SugerirCategoriaPage');
              }

              guardarConsultaDeSugerirCategoria() {
                console.log(this.formularioSugerirCategoria.value);
              }

              private crearFormularioDeSugerirCategoria() {
                return this.formBuilder.group({
                  comentario1: ['', Validators.required],
                  comentario2: ['', Validators.required],
                });
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conozco 2 opciones:

1) Utilizar el plugin [email-composer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/) que te permite "crear" un email, especificando destinatario, asunto, contenido, etc, y despues le envía todos estos datos a la aplicación de email por defecto que esté instalada en el dispositivo.

2) Crear un servicio web que se encargue del envío al cual le envíes todos los parámetros, esto puede variar segun las herramientas que utilices en tu backend. En el caso de PHP sería con la función [Mail](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp).

Comment: Gracias al final opté por usar PHPmailer que lo integré con slim para el backend en mi proyecto con ionic